# Safari is returning the wrong width value

Tags: javascript, safari, offsetwidth

Hi I have a table with a div in it the table has 2 columns and both are 50% 
In most browsers I can use offsetWidth to get the width of the article.
But in Safari the width is less or more than what it should be.
Any help would be greatly appriciated.
Regards
Richard

Comment: Could you post here code for these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the width and height - safari's bug -just accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`offsetWidth` is not a standardized value across browsers. It may or may not include the scroll-bar width. You may get more consistent figures from `clientWidth` which tends to exclude margins, borders and scrollbars.

Comment: According to this http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html it seems not to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the value of offsetWidth is gathered in different time that in other browsers. Try calling it in onload or ondomready event.